# Can I setup geolocation(devtools>sensors) with puppeteer api and node.js

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I need setup geolocation(lat, lng) in devtools>sensors of chrome with puppeteer api

if I set it with:

```
    // enable geolocation
    const context = browser.defaultBrowserContext();
    await context.overridePermissions(url, ['geolocation']);
    // set current location to Tokyo Station
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await client.send('Emulation.setGeolocationOverride', {
        latitude: 43.0642,
        longitude: 141.347,
        accuracy: 100
    });
```

[see bottom-right: devtools geolocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4gTj.jpg)

this code setup geolocation in page navigation.geolocation(but not in devtools) and work for some sites, for example https://map.ultra-zone.net/g/,
but if I try "google search", it gave me results not right for the geolocation.
Another way, if I set geolocation manually in devtools>sensors then result is right

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 250,
        devtools: true
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const url = 'https://map.ultra-zone.net/g/';
    // enable geolocation
    const context = browser.defaultBrowserContext();
    await context.overridePermissions(url, ['geolocation']);
    // set current location to Tokyo Station
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await client.send('Emulation.setGeolocationOverride', {
        latitude: 43.0642,
        longitude: 141.347,
        accuracy: 100
    });
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.screenshot({
        path: 'example.png'
    });
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                resolve({ lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude });
            });
        });
    });
    console.log(result);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Can anybody describe me how to set geolocation in devtools>sensors with puppeteer api or maybe over 'userDataDir' launchPuppeteerOptions?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the only thing that "google search" uses is the geolocation feature?

Answer (score 1):

I set `await page.setGeolocation({latitude: X, longitude: Y});` after page load. It wasn't working when I initially set it up.